# How to split a code into two .java files in a same directory (using classes)?

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to split one code into two .java files but it's showing me the following error. What should I do to make it run properly?

```
//this is Node.java
public class Node() {
    public int data;
    public Node next;

    public insert(){
        System.out.println("node is working");
    }
}

//this is LL.java
class LL{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node n=new Node();
        n.insert(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What "following error", I don't see an error written here.

Comment: Provide error details.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show the error message, but presumably you forgot to import it.

```
// This is LL.java
import Node;
class LL{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Node n=new Node();
    n.insert(); 
    }
}
```